# My client app can't connect to the server

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

My client app can't connect to the server.

This is my server code

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    log("Starting server...");
    
    try {
        
    server = new ServerSocket(6969);
        
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(thread3);
    
    log("Started server");
    
}




static Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    
    public void run () {
        
        while(true) {
            
            try {
                
                System.out.println("TEST 1");
                
                Socket s = server.accept();

                System.out.println("TEST 2");
                
                log("Connection estabilished with: " + s.getInetAddress());
                                    
                new EchoThread(s).start();      
                            
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
};
```

And after server start console prints:

```
       Starting server...
       TEST 1
       Started server
```

And this is my client code:

```
      System.out.println("TEST 1");

      s = new Socket("193.168.242.30", 6969);

      System.out.println("TEST 2");
```

And console only prints "TEST 1", but does not print "TEST 2" so problem is at line "          s = new Socket("193.168.242.30", 6969);
"

Comment: Except to support legacy systems, there is (almost) no reason to be using Socket / ServerSocket anymore. Use WebSockets instead. as it automatically takes care of a lot of the plumbing involved with sockets via standard protocols

Comment: *Unless* you are required to use these classes as part of an academic assignment requirement -- then you're stuck